# Filtering out string values in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python Pandas.

For example, I have a dataframe as follows

```
index, name, acct_no, city
1, alex, 10011, huntington
2, rider, 100AB, charleston
3, daniel, A1009, bonn
4, rice, AAAA1, new york
5, ricardo, 12121, london
```

From this dataset, I would like to get ONLY those
records who donot have any string in the **acct_no** column.

So, I would like to get the following result from the above dataset. In the following result, there is no string in the values of the **acct_no** column.

```
index, name, acct_no, city
1, alex, 10011, huntington
5, ricardo, 12121, london
```

Which code will give me such result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May check `str.contains`

```
df1=df[~df.acct_no.str.contains('[a-zA-Z]')]
df1
Out[119]: 
   index      name acct_no         city
0      1      alex   10011   huntington
4      5   ricardo   12121       london
```

Or using `to_numeric` and filter by `notna`

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.acct_no,errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use pd.to_numeric, which tries to convert a value to a number. When it fails we can let it return nan (by specifying errors='coerce'), and then we drop all nan values:

```
df.acct_no = pd.to_numeric(df.acct_no, errors='coerce')
df.dropna()
```